# Powershell apply action on each subfolder

Tags: xml, powershell-3.0

I need a little help with a PS script I have written. I am inexperienced with Powershell, but based on what I have found online I was able to write a script to accomplish what I want. However, I can't get it to work on any subfolders.

Currently I have a folder called "C:\Temp\Test". Inside of that folder there are numerous subfolders, one for each user, named Greg, Tom, Alice, etc. So the folder structure looks like this

C:\Temp\Test\Greg

C:\Temp\Test\Tom

C:\Temp\Test\Alice

etc...

Each person's subfolder contains dozens and sometimes hundreds of .JPG and .TIF picture files. Each picture file needs to have a .XML file with the same name that contains properties such as name & date of birth and such. I have created the first .XML file for each user and created the following script to scan the folder and create the .XML file for each remaining picture file. Then copy the contents of the first .XML file into the newly created files. Here is what I have so far:

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\Test\*" -Recurse -File -Include *.tif,*jpg
$destinationFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\Test" -Recurse -File -Filter *.xml

foreach($sourceFile in $sourceFiles) {
  $exists = $destinationFiles | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -eq $sourceFile.BaseName}
  if(!$exists) {
    New-Item -type File "C:\Temp\Test\$($sourceFile.BaseName).xml"
  }
}

$file1 = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\Test" -Filter *.xml | Select-Object -First 1
$file2 = Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\Test" -Filter *.xml -recurse -Exclude $file1

cd "C:\Temp\Test"
Get-Content $file1 | Add-Content $file2
```

When I had the test pictures in the "C:\Temp\Test" directory, the script worked perfectly. What I can't figure out, is how to change the script to run on each person's subfolder and place the new .XML files in the subfolder that the pictures are located in. If anyone has any ideas about how I could do this, or how I could improve this script I would greatly appreciate your thoughts. As I said, I am not very experienced with PS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure , But try by using this.

```
# This will split the path and give parent folder
$ParentFullPath = Split-Path $sourceFile.BaseName -Parent

# This will give you the parent folder name
$ParentPath = Split-Path $ParentFullPath -Leaf

New-Item -type File "C:\Temp\Test\$ParentPath\$($sourceFile.BaseName).xml"
```

Good to read Get-Help Split-Path -Full

Regards,

kvprasoon

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Prasoon! I ended up putting this project on hold for awhile and when I picked it back up, I reworked what I had done. After spending some time learning Powershell a little better I came up with something that was almost exactly what I wanted. I felt I should share it in case anyone else is stuck on a similar issue.

```
#This is the Template File

$file1 = "C:\Temp\000.xml"

#This browses through each subfolder and finds any files that are JPG or PNG 
files. 

Get-ChildItem -recurse -force | ForEach {
If (($_.extension -eq ".tif") -or ($_.extension -eq ".jpg"))

#This creates a new XML file for each image file found in the previous step 
and gives it the same name as the image file. It then copies the contents of 
the XML Template file into the new XML file.

{New-Item -type File -Path $($_.DirectoryName) -Name "$($_.BaseName).xml"   
-value "$(Get-Content $file1)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
}

#After the XML files are created, this finds any XML files in 
subdirectories. It then looks for the \record\name element and updates it to 
the name of the folder that the file is located in.

Get-ChildItem -include *.xml -recurse | % ($_) {
[xml]$xml = Get-Content ("$($_.Fullname)")
$xml.record.name = (Get-
Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase("$($_.Directory.BaseName.ToLower())")
$xml.save("$($_.Fullname)")}
```

The folders that the image and XML files are in are all capital. (i.e JOHN DOE).  I wanted the 'name' element in the XML files to be title case instead of all caps, and so the last part of the code pulls the folder name that XML file resides in and converts it from JOHN DOE to John Doe. Then puts that value in 'name' element of the XML file.

Hopefully someone finds this script useful.